# JSON - Count number of items in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I have a Json object as follows:

```
jsonobject = {
"fruits": [
    {
        "name": "A",
        "uri": "a.com"
    },
    {
        "name": "B",
        "uri": "b.com"
    }
],
"trees": [
    {
        "name": "t1",
        "uri": "t1.com",
        "status": null
    },
    {
        "name": "t2",
        "uri": "t2.com",
        "status": null
    }
]
}
```

How to get the number of trees/fruits in Ruby?

Comment: Can you make clear the context of this code?

Comment: I am getting this json object as a output of HTTP GET request. Now I just want to count the number of items inside "fruits" and "trees". I have used these names instead of the info I am actually getting. Just not to disclose the information. Can you help now?

Comment: `json = JSON.parse(jsonobject)["trees"].size`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, a small correction. Your jsonobject should be a string. Enclose the entire jsonobject in single quotes.

```
jsonobject = '{"fruits": [{"name": "A","uri": "a.com"},{"name": "B","uri": "b.com"}],"trees": [{"name": "t1","uri": "t1.com","status": null},{"name": "t2","uri": "t2.com","status": null}]}'
```

You can make use of the JSON library of ruby here...

number of trees

```
JSON.parse(jsonobject)["trees"].size
```

number of fruits

```
JSON.parse(jsonobject)["fruits"].size
```

**UPDATE:**
How to make the jsonobject as string

jsonobject = %q({"fruits": [{"name": "A","uri": "a.com"},{"name": "B","uri": "b.com"}],"trees": [{"name": "t1","uri": "t1.com","status": null},{"name": "t2","uri": "t2.com","status": null}]})

Comment: That is actually the issue. I am getting the input without single quotes. How to make it to string first in ruby?

Comment: It worked. Thanks a ton. A small doubt. If i have jsonobject as a output of some other program and I want to count the elements how can I do that without writing it in separate program. Can I write jsonobject = %qjsonobject?

Comment: Is it possible to share the code where actually you receive the jsonobject. What language you use in that another program. It would be better if you can post a new question related to this.